# Месяц май внутри даты звучит косноязычно

Tags: дефект, локализация

Даты на сайте используют первые три буквы месяца, и одиннадцать месяцев в году их окончания можно додумывать на свой вкус.

Но `май` сам по себе состоит из трёх букв, и поэтому майские даты оказываются "пришпилены" к именительному падежу. Они всюду звучат косноязычно, поскольку внутри даты мы произносим месяца в родительном падеже.

> ответ дан 7 май в 15:41
>
> изменён 6 май '15 в 7:10
>
> Последнее посещение 1 май в 8:40

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю перевести английское `May` как русское `мая`, в родительном падеже.

Comment: Да и `'15` выглядит достаточно не по-русски. У нас год так не сокращают.

Comment: @VladD Было бы круто настраивать формат даты при локализации. Мне кажется, это достаточно естественная необходимость не только для русского языка. Как узнать, что для этого нужно?

Comment: Думаю, пингануть Николаса в чате :) Пусть создаст тикет команде локализаторов.

Comment: [Нельзя так переводить однозначно.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5192/176217)