# Неправильный падеж месяца

Tags: дефект, локализация, даты

Неправильно отображается падеж месяца в дате задания вопроса:

> задан 3 май в 16:27

ожидалось:

> задан 3 мая в 16:27

или

> задан 3.05 в 16:27

Answer (score 3):

С одной стороны неправильно, а с другой - правильно. В дате задания вопроса, как в некоторых других местах, используется 3-4х-буквенное сокращение названия месяца. И май единственный месяц, который умещается полностью в эти размеры. Но так как название месяца используется в разных контекстах, простая замена "май" на "мая" может создать проблемы в других местах, например при просмотре графика репутации:

> [image: репутация]

На текущий момент вижу несколько решений:

- разделять контексты и использовать наиболее подходящий перевод
- использовать единый формат и единый перевод везде

Оба решения будут требовать участие разработчиков в разрешении проблемы. Обычным изменением существующего перевода проблему решить не получится, т.к.
"май" в transifex задаётся пока в [единственной варианте](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261785?key=195fbb57ffe7449796d23466085ce6d8).

По поводу отображения дат на ruSO мною было заведено уже пара баг-репортов на MSE:

- [Date format in reputation graph should use national standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290392/339911)
- [Date for per day table is not able to localize in reputation graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291502/339911)

При желании можете поддержать их своим голосом. Хотя уверенности в том, что это как-то поможет сдвинуть проблему с мёртвой точки, нет.